# Getting text from a .txt file in a variable

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

So I have this html file with some A-frame Code (It just adds a ball to the scene). And a .js script which contains functions that can move the ball, like moveUp();. Now I want to be able to execute some JavaScript code (that uses the move fuctions) written in a .txt file using the eval of JavaScript.

But client side JavaScript can't read or write a .txt file (I don't want to choose the file myself at runtime). Is there a way to get the data of a .txt file in a JavaScript var without having to set up a server and using server side JavaScript?

Comment: It is possible to upload the file, open it and read it on the client only. No server needed

Comment: "Now I want to be able to execute some JavaScript code (that uses the move fuctions) written in a .txt file using the eval of JavaScript." — Forget about eval. Just load it with a `<script>` element!

Comment: You mean by using something like a 'choose file' button and selecting the .txt file yourself?

Comment: As Quentin says, change the .txt file to a .js file and load it before your other scripts.

Comment: But in a later stage i will have to be able to write text (code) to that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make a recommendation as to how you might proceed. It sounds like what you really need is a way of allowing a user to save `commands`, rather than actual `code`, to a file, and then allow those commands to be loaded again and to influence the position etc of the shape on the screen.

Let's say you have a `move` function that takes in `object`, `x` and `y` arguments:

```
function move(obj, x, y) {
  // Move obj using x and y coords
}
```

Maybe you have a form that allows the user to input those coords, but somehow you want to save those coords along with the action (`move`).

The simplest way of doing that is to use an array of objects. The advantageof this is you can then `stringify` into JSON, save that data, and reload it and parse it back to your application to your heart's content.

For example you might save your data as a series of commands in an array like this:

```
const commands = [
  { action: 'move', x: 30, y: 50 },
  { action: 'move', x: 300, y: 510 }
];
```

You can add more command objects by `push`ing them on to the array.

Then you might have an object containing some action functions. Let's use `move` again:

```
const commandFns = {
  move: function (obj, x, y) {
    // Move obj using x and y coords
  }
}
```

So to move the fire off the commands you just iterate over the actions array, calling the appropriate function.

```
const obj = currentShapeToBeMoved;
commands.forEach(({ action, x, y }) => actionFns[action](obj, x, y));
```

To save the commands you `JSON.stringify(commands)` the commands data object. Maybe save that to a file to disk, or perhaps even better, `localStorage`.

To load the file back into the application, find where you've saved the data and then `JSON.parse(data)` back into its array form.

In short, you don't *append* anything to the file. All you're doing is loading data, updating the the data in your application, then saving *the same/amended data* back.